# IndentationError: expected an indented block in an indented block

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

i have a problem in my code i have no idea how to fix
i even tried to put 5 indents in the same line yet it didnt help
if i am in the wrong here can someone rewrite my code please so it will work? i have sat for about 40m and still couldnt figure out the problem thanks!

```
def grade_len(password):
    if(len(password) <= 4):
        return 0
    if(5 <= len(password) <= 7):
        return 5
    if(len(password) > 7):
        return 10

def grade_used(password):
    if(password[0:9] == 'password' or 'love' in password or 'qwerty' in password or 'abc' in password):
        return 0
    else:
        return 10   



def grade_vari(password):
    if(re.search('[a-z]',password) == False):
        return 0
    if(password.isalpha()):
        return 3
    if(password.lower == password.lower and password.isalpha() == False):
        return 5
    if(re.search('[a-z]',password) and re.search('[A-Z]',password) and re.search('[0-9]',password)):
        return 7
    if(re.search('[0-9]',password) and re.search('[a-z]',password) and re.search('[A-Z]',password) and re.match("[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;'\[\]]", password)):
        return 10




def main():
    password = raw_input ("enter password:")
    test1 = grade_len(password)
    test2 = grade_used(password)
    test3 = grade_vari(password)
    test_num = 3
    test_average = (test1+test2+test3)/3
    if(test_average<4):
        print("Weak")
    if(4<=test_average<=6):
        print("Medium")
    if(7<=test_average<=8):
        print("Strong")
    if(9<=test_average<=10):
        print("Very strong")    

main()
```

Comment: Have you imported `re` in your file?

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: You should use 4 spaces for one level indent. And consistent - always 4 space for every indent level.

This error appears probably, because in one place you have one space to less or to more. Look also if you have not mixed tabs and spaces in your code (a good IDE should handle this).

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ yes, i just didn't include this in this code

Comment: Other than that your code seems ok. Just copy and paste the code from here, and it should run. Why? Take a look at bodolsog's comment above. If you still face problem, show us the error you get while running it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a silly mistake, you forgot to import re. this works

```
import re 
def grade_len(password):
    if(len(password) <= 4):
        return 0
    if(5 <= len(password) <= 7):
        return 5
    if(len(password) > 7):
        return 10

def grade_used(password):
    if(password[0:9] == 'password' or 'love' in password or 'qwerty' in password or 'abc' in password):
        return 0
    else:
        return 10



def grade_vari(password):
    if(re.search('[a-z]',password) == False):
        return 0
    if(password.isalpha()):
        return 3
    if(password.lower == password.lower and password.isalpha() == False):
        return 5
    if(re.search('[a-z]',password) and re.search('[A-Z]',password) and re.search('[0-9]',password)):
        return 7
    if(re.search('[0-9]',password) and re.search('[a-z]',password) and re.search('[A-Z]',password) and re.match("[~\!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)_\+{}\":;'\[\]]", password)):
        return 10




def main():
    password = raw_input ("enter password:")
    test1 = grade_len(password)
    test2 = grade_used(password)
    test3 = grade_vari(password)
    test_num = 3
    test_average = (test1+test2+test3)/3
    if(test_average<4):
        print("Weak")
    if(4<=test_average<=6):
        print("Medium")
    if(7<=test_average<=8):
        print("Strong")
    if(9<=test_average<=10):
        print("Very strong")

main()
```

Comment: thank you! i am new to python. this is my 5th program and i don't really know a lot about all the libraries. thank you very much! you saved me a lot of time

Comment: I understand learning is a tough process, make sure you use an IDE like Pycharm or something(pick your favorite). This is a simple error which can be caught by an IDE. You can download community edition from here  https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/.. Good Luck with programming :)